Error on mountig Windows 11 share on Ubuntu Server (or Desktop) 24.04
I am trying to mount a Windows 11 share on Ubuntu Linux, version 24.04, both desktop and server edition, with no success.
I tried the following command:
mount -t cifs -o user=guest,password= //host/share mountingPoint
I got this error message:
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

And from dmesg:
[349174.481029] CIFS: Attempting to mount //host/share
[349174.487746] CIFS: VFS: parse_reparse_point: unhandled reparse tag: 0x9000701a
[349174.487775] CIFS: VFS: cifs_read_super: get root inode failed

The exact same command works perfectly on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.
What am I missing? I realize that these versions are very new and maybe buggy, but peharps I missing something obvious.
